# Warning: include_once(D:\XAMPP\htdocs\_includes itle.php)

Tags: php

so i tried to include these files

```
include_once(__DIR__."\_includes\title.php;
include_once(__DIR__."\_includes\variables.php;
```

it spit out error

> Warning: include_once(D:\XAMPP\htdocs_includes itle.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php on line 9

notice that it doesnt output full string `_includes\title` only `_includes itle`

why is this?
and how to solve this?

Comment: Use single quotes or double back slashes. In a double quote, the string `\t` is a control character for a tab. So `"includes\title.php"` translates into: `_includes{a-tab-character}itle.php`.

Comment: Could you copy the include line from your code? At the moment the include line doesn't compile and doesn't match the error message. Copy and pasting is important for any hidden whitespaces that could cause this error

Comment: Remember that \ is the escape character in php string, you need to double it up if you want it in a string

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this:

```
include_once __DIR__.'\_includes\title.php';
```